# SQL C# - filter identical entries via latest date

Tags: c#, sql, select, oledb

I'm accessing a database from C# via SQL commands and was wondering how I could read back the whole table, but only with the latest date for each entry.  My Table is as follows:

Table:

```
ID Name    Begin Date    Job    Area    Co-worker
--------------------------------------------------
1          1/01/2001     M1     Comp3   John Do
1          1/01/2003     M1     Comp3   Jane Do
1          1/01/2010     C2     Comp3   Jane Do
2          1/01/2010     C2     Comp3   John Do
3          12/01/2003    A6     Comp1   Smith John
3          12/01/2004    M2     Comp3   Smith Jack
```

etc...

I know that the table has multiple entries with the same ID, at different dates with different jobs/co-workers.  I just want to loop through and for every ID, grab the latest information for that ID.  I've looked for hours and can't seem to find anything that works (C# seems to have a hard time using SQL JOIN commands).  I've tried a few different ways such as:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [A & C] INNER JOIN(SELECT [ID Name], MAX([Begin Date]) AS MaxDate, Job, [Job Area], Co-Worker FROM [A & C] GROUP BY [ID Name]) [A & C] ON([A & C]", connectionObject);
```

but can't seem to get anything to work (I've tried it a number of ways and realised the problem must be with me looking at this wrong), can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [A & C] INNER JOIN
     (SELECT [ID Name], MAX([Begin Date]) AS MaxDate, Job, [Job Area], Co-Worker
      FROM [A & C]
      GROUP BY [ID Name]
     ) [A & C]
     ON ([A & C];
```

I think you want this:

```
SELECT ac.*
FROM [A & C] as ac INNER JOIN
     (SELECT [ID Name], MAX([Begin Date]) AS MaxDate
      FROM [A & C] as ac
      GROUP BY [ID Name]
     ) as ac2
     ON ac.[ID Name] = ac2.[ID Name] and ac.[Begin Date] = ac2.MaxDate;
```

Comment: I tried! Thankyou for your answer but i got an error :( 
Openning: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in FROM clause.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) ----- Thankyou for being so quick!

Comment: looked at it again and tried this as my SQL command:
SELECT ac.* FROM [A & C] AS ac INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [ID Name], MAX([Begin Date]) AS MaxDate FROM [A & C] AS ac GROUP BY [ID Name]) AS ac2 ON ac.[ID Name] = ac2.[ID Name] AND ac.[Begin Date] = ac2.MaxDate
I now have an error telling me that 'A & C' can't be found... HELP!

Comment: @blindman457 . . . I can't help with that.  You need to use the correct name of your tables for any query to work.  I would suggest you start with a simpler query, just to be sure the connection and names are working.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, I realised that half the tables weren't actually in the access file, rather, they were only referenced by it, could I still access these referenced tables or would I have to go straight to the other file that contains it?